# Angular 11 Select All, Deselect All check boxes like Gmail

Tags: angular, angular11

I am trying to do check boxes with select all and deselect all options.

I have faced an issue that,

first I checked all option(that works), secondly I uncheck one or more checkboxs(NOT CheckALL one)(that is also works). finally i check all option(**This does not works**)

(when I select all options that is OK ( all checkbox are checked)
when I deselect all options that is OK ( all checkbox are unchecked))

Output is :

[image: Screenshot of Output]

.component.ts file

```js
checkedRow = false;
checkedAll = false;
checkedRows = [];


AllSelectedHandler(checked: boolean, book) {
    const idArr = book.map(i => i.id);
    console.log("ID array " + idArr);

    if (checked == true) {
      this.checkedAll = true;
      this.checkedRow = true;

      idArr.forEach(id => {

        if (this.checkedAll == true) {
          this.checkedRow = true;
          console.log("checkedRow works ")
          console.log(this.checkedRow)
        }

        if (this.checkedRows.includes(id)) {
          this.checkedRows.push();
          console.log("if works");
        }
        else {
          this.checkedRows.push(id);
         // this.checkedRow = true;
          console.log("else works");
          console.log("id is " + id);
        }

      });

      console.log(this.checkedRows);
      console.log("checked row" + this.checkedRows);

      const numSelected = this.checkedRows.length;
      console.log("no of selected" + numSelected);
    }
    else {
      this.checkedAll = false;
      this.checkedRow = false;
      this.checkedRows = [];
      this.multipleDelete = false;
      console.log(this.checkedRows);
    }
    const numRows = this.books.length;
    console.log("no of rows " + numRows);
}
```

.html

```html
<nb-checkbox 
  [value]= "books" 
  [checked]="checkedAll" 
  (checkedChange)="AllSelectedHandler($event, books)" >
</nb-checkbox>
                        
<nb-checkbox 
  value={{data.id}} 
  [checked]="checkedRow"
  (checkedChange)="CheckboxChangeHandler($event, data.id)">
</nb-checkbox>
```

In console:

```
ID array 23,22,21,2,1

checkedRow works 
true
else works
id is 23

checkedRow works 
true
else works
id is 22

checkedRow works 
true
if works

checkedRow works 
true
if works

checkedRow works 
true
if works

(5) [21, 2, 1, 23, 22]

checkedrows 21,2,1,23,22

no of selected 5

no of rows 5
```

**Here notice that All checkedRow values are true. But in output check box is unchecked.**

Please can anyone tell me what is the issue?

Comment: Are u storing the ids (23, 22, 21, 2, 1) in any array or how you are displaying them in your page (in ur screenshot)?

Comment: i store checked Ids as an array into checkedRows- this is an array. see above i have edited now.

Comment: make a runnable code on https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

You keep a second array(e.g.: selectedItems), like you are doing, to store selected items. When checking a box, just push the item to this array.

To select all, just copy the original array to selectedItems. To unselect all set it to [ ].

Then just make the checkboxes appear checked when selectedItems contains the item.

In template:

```html
...
[checked]="inSelectedItems(id)"
...
```

In component:

```js
inSelectedItems(id: number): boolean {
  return selectedItems.includes(id)
}
```

There is no need for all the checks and a forEach this way.

Comment: Sorry for not testing the code or making a project, I'm happy to take a look if you post a stackblitz. But I think this should be clear and might help you get on the right pad.